# how to show price under all days in daterangepicker ?(not use hover show price)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, daterangepicker

how do I show price under days?  not show Thanks a lot

Hi Im using [this plugin](https://www.daterangepicker.com/), and encountered a problem while hover show price. I manage do show price under days in daterangepicker .

code

hoverDate: function(e) hover in daterangepicker

renderCalendar: function(side) show days

Comment: Hey @sia7 which `daterangepicker` are you using?

Comment: https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could fork your own copy of the library and modify the source code. Otherwise [this](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/blob/8495717c4007a03fd5dee422f161811fd6140c0e/daterangepicker.js#L840) appears to be the line which generates the contents of the calendar and does not support custom value injection :(